# Pink and Blue Hairs in Edit Mode?

Tags: edit-mode, import

After importing a file, the resulting mesh is covered in pink and blue hair looking lines.  I'm not sure why this happens and would like to make them not visible so I can actually manipulate the mesh... Any help would be appreciated.

[[image: Image]]

Please see [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g080w.jpg)

Comment: What object is it and where was it imported from. What file format did it come in? Could we have a look at said file?

Comment: It's a .rip file from Ninja Ripper... I can provide the .rip or a .blend with the imported mesh?

Comment: Never heard of rip or Ninja Rippern not sure I'd be able to import it. A **as simplified as possible** [file showing the problem](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) would probably be best. Those look like mesh normal indicators but the colors don't seem to match